# API calls that return select post bodies throw JSON errors

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2.1, posts

When calling the Stack Exchange API to get the post body, it will return an error for some posts. EG:
[/docs/questions#page=13&pagesize=100&fromdate=2013-09-01&todate=2013-09-02&order=asc&sort=creation&filter=!9ciXf5l7v&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=13&pagesize=100&fromdate=2013-09-01&todate=2013-09-02&order=asc&sort=creation&filter=!9ciXf5l7v&site=stackoverflow&run=true)
throws:

> Invalid JSON returned

But if we exclude the post body, EG:
[/docs/questions#page=13&pagesize=100&fromdate=2013-09-01&todate=2013-09-02&order=asc&sort=creation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=13&pagesize=100&fromdate=2013-09-01&todate=2013-09-02&order=asc&sort=creation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)
, it works fine.

We suspect it’s because the post body contains some characters like “\0” which makes the returned JSON invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.

Root cause: I had let a copy of our JSON serializer (currently [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text)) get out of date.